What’s horizon tilt in Tilt to Steer - Asphalt Legends Unite
Under the Tilt to Steer setting, there’s a box that you can check with the words “Horizon Tilt” next to it.
What is Horizon Tilt?

I saw the setting on iOS, and I’m not sure if the tilt to steer setting exists on other platforms.

I found this Reddit with a comment that linked to two videos showing the difference:

With Horizon tilt on
With Horizon tilt off

Here are some screenshots from the videos at roughly the same location. With it on, the whole game world appears to rotate with your car as it makes sharp turns, tilting the horizon with your turns.  This screenshot is from the "With Horizon tilt on" video:

With it off, the game world doesn't rotate with your car as it makes sharp turns.  This screenshot is from the "With Horizon tilt off" video:

